# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two operands in if statement

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Given the following `struct`:

```
struct Landmark {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

And the following `@State`:

```
@State var landmarks: [Landmark] = [
    Landmark(id: "1", name: "Sydney Harbour Bridge", location: .init(latitude: -33.852222, longitude: 151.210556)),
    Landmark(id: "2", name: "Brooklyn Bridge", location: .init(latitude: 40.706, longitude: -73.997))
]

private func selectNextLandmark() {
    if let selectedLandmark = selectedLandmark, let currentIndex = landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selectedLandmark }), currentIndex + 1 < landmarks.endIndex {
        self.selectedLandmark = landmarks[currentIndex + 1]
    } else {
        selectedLandmark = landmarks.first
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the `if` line inside `selectNextLandmark`:

> Operator function '==' requires that 'Landmark' conform to 'Equatable'

Is there a problem with my `Landmark` `struct` or is it a problem with the `if` statement syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is quite clear

> Operator function '==' requires that 'Landmark' conform to 'Equatable'

The struct `Landmark` must conform to `Equatable` protocol in order for it to know what equality means in reference to the Struct. Update your struct to

```
struct Landmark: Equatable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    static func == (lhs: Landmark, rhs: Landmark) -> Bool {
        //Your equating logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as you answered the question I tried conforming to `Equatable` and wasn't actually sure how the `static func` was meant to look like. Thanks for providing that in the answer!

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: If all properties are `Equatable` too you don't even need to write equality operator function.

Comment: @user28434 of course. I forgot to mention that in my answer. Good point